# How to display form data in a table on the same page upon pressing submit?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, web

How to display form data in a table on the same page upon pressing submit?

This is my form

```
<form method="post" target="_parent">

    <p>Name: 
      <input type="text" name="Name" value="" maxlength="200" size="60">
    </p>

    <p>User ID:
        <input type="text" name="UserID" value="" maxlength="200" size="60">
    </p>

    <p>Password:
        <input type="password" name="Password" value="" maxlength="200" size="60">
    </p>

    <p>Organization:
        <input type="text" name="Organization" value="" maxlength="200" size="60">
    </p>

    <p> Role
      <select name="Role">
        <option name = "Member" selected>Member</option>
        <option name = "Admin">Admin</option>
      </select>
    </p><br />
    <p> 
      <input type="submit" name="submit">
      <input type="button" name="cancel" value="Cancel" onClick="closebox()">
    </p>
</form>
```

This is my adding table row code

```
function addrow()
{
    var table=document.getElementById("tablelist");
    var row=table.insertRow(-1);
    var cells = new Array();
    for(var i = 0; i < 6;i++)
    {
        cells[i]=row.insertCell(i);
        cells[i].innerHTML="New";
    }
}
```

I want a new row to be added to the table with the form data in the cells upon pressing submit but i have no idea where to begin.

Comment: prevent the usual submission of form using jquery and ajax

Comment: if you want to stay in the same page don't use submit, use button type instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your form has not so many inputs and you want a simple script, this small scripts will do all for you.

Check DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/S4FT7/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submit').on('click',function(){
        var st = '';
        $('#myForm input[type=text],input[type=password],select').each(function(){
            st = st+ '<td>'+$(this).val()+'</td>';
            $(this).val('');
        });
        $('#details').append('<tr>'+st+'</tr>');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, considering you are using post as the form method, you would send the data to a script to be processed. The response from that script would then be used to generate your new table. 
You can use client side scripting (javascript/jquery) to validate your form before sending to a server side script such as php.

You might like to look at the jquery [.serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) function as it provides a simple way to send your data to a server side script, and to manipulate the returned data.

Example code might look something like:

client side jquery post call

```
.post(serverSideScript.php',$('#yourFormId').serialize()).success(genResults);
```

this calls the `genResults` function when your serverside script completes successfully

callback function

```
//display a new table with whatever info you like
function formSent(data){   
  var newTR = '<table><tr>' 
        + '<td>Display a result ' 
        + $('#userId').val() 
        + '</td></tr></table>';

//append to your table,
$('body').append(newTR);

}
```

If you dont want/need to process the form then client side scripting is your friend. Simply create a table on form submit.

With jQuery it looks something like

```
$('#yourFormId').submit(function(e){

//prevent the default form action
e.preventDefault();

//display a new table with whatever info you like

      var newTR = '<table><tr>' 
            + '<td>Display a result ' 
            + $('#userId').val() 
            + '</td></tr></table>';

    //append to your table,
    $('body').append(newTR);
});
```

hope this is of some help...

Answer (score 1):

JQuery and CSS should do the work.. hide and show of form

First the form, as you want in a row of your table.

```
<tr>
 <td>
   <div class="myForm hide">
     <form>...</form>
   </div>
 </td>
</tr>
```

in your JQuery/javascript

```
$('.button').click(function(){
  $('.myForm').show();
});
```

This should do the trick

Comment: I do not want to hide or show the form. What i wanted was when the submit button is pressed, a new row would be added on the table with the form data.

Comment: so there could be a many rows and a form on each row?

Comment: no.. the form is not part of the table. the form is outside of the table. There could be many rows if the form is submitted many times.

Comment: okay to make things easier you're creating many users here? and when submitted you just save those user details?

Comment: the FORM is outside of the table. What i want is the FORM DATA, which is the UserID, Name, password, etc.., to be output on a new row upon pressing the submit button.

Comment: i already see what you want, refining my answer